# Why does this TaskFailedException happened?

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, julia

I apologize if this question is too long I couldn't find a better way to ask this question. So I am not an expert in parallel computing, and this is the biggest code I've written using it, it is an MCMC code but I want to use parallel computing in Julia to get better results.

```
@everywhere function relay_basis(alpha,delta,name::String,n)   #n is the number of sources for 1 relay we have 2 sources
    
    chi = fill(sqrt(0.06), n)                  # the parameter chi 
    phi = im*tanh.(chi)
    omega = 1.0 / prod(cosh.(chi))^2
    syms, op = qrelay_op(n, phi, alpha, delta)
    op_a, op_ab, mat, coef = op_mat(op)

    op_q2 = [syms.apH[1], syms.apV[1], syms.bpH[end], syms.bpV[end]]
    op_q1 = [syms.apH[2:end]..., syms.apV[2:end]..., syms.bpH[1:end-1]..., syms.bpV[1:end-1]...]
    mask_q1 = [op in op_q1 for op in op_a];
    
    mask_q2 = [op in op_q2 for op in op_a];
    qq = [x in syms.apH || x in syms.bpV ? 1 : 0 for x in op_a]
           
    pdet0 = pdet_maker(0.04, 1e-5)
    qrs = QRelaySampler(mat, coef, omega, pdet0)
    targetcache=Dict{Vector{Int}, Float64}()
    target(x::Vector)= log(qrs.prob(qq, x, mask_q1) * qrs.prob(x))      #the target function of MCMC
    Iteration=100_000 
    burnin=1000
    samples=Iteration+burnin
    step=25
    save_iter=burnin:step:samples
    dist= qrs.psetproposal           #the proposal distribution
    selected=[]
    Q = []
    
    current_x = zeros(length(qq))
    @time @distributed (+) for i= 2:samples            #from this line the MCMC algorithm starts
        
        proposed_x= rand(dist(current_x))
        
        prop_proposed= pdf(dist(current_x), proposed_x)
        
        prop_current= pdf(dist(proposed_x), current_x)
        
        C=prop_current/ prop_proposed
        
        A= min(1,C * exp(target(proposed_x) - target( current_x)))
        
        
        if rand() < A
            if i in save_iter
                 push!(selected, proposed_x)
                 push!(Q, qrs.prob(qq, proposed_x, mask_q2))
             end        
    
            current_x = proposed_x
        end
        
    end
    
    return selected, Q
end
```

I call this function:

```
for i = 0:2
    beta = i*pi/2
    name = string(i)
    selected, Q = relay_basis(pi/4, beta, name,2)
    println("beta:", beta)
    push!(prob,Q)
    df=DataFrame(selected=selected)

end
```

And I get this long error message:

```
TaskFailedException

    nested task error: MethodError: no method matching write(::Sockets.TCPSocket, ::Cstring)
    Closest candidates are:
      write(::IO, ::Any) at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/base/io.jl:637
      write(::IO, ::Any, ::Any...) at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/base/io.jl:638
      write(::FilePathsBase.AbstractPath, ::Any) at ~/.julia/packages/FilePathsBase/dVWLK/src/path.jl:771
      ...
    Stacktrace:
      [1] write(io::Sockets.TCPSocket, x::Cstring)
        @ Base ./io.jl:637
      [2] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:664
      [3] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
      [4] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
      [5] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
      [6] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
      [7] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
      [8] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
      [9] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
     [10] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
     [11] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
     [12] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
     [13] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
     [14] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
     [15] serialize
        @ /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653 [inlined]
     [16] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, a::Vector{JuMP.VariableRef})
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:277
     [17] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
     [18] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
     [19] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
     [20] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
     [21] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
     [22] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
     [23] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
     [24] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
     [25] serialize_any(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:674
     [26] serialize(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, x::Any)
        @ Serialization /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Serialization/src/Serialization.jl:653
     [27] serialize_msg(s::Distributed.ClusterSerializer{Sockets.TCPSocket}, o::Distributed.CallMsg{:call_fetch})
        @ Distributed /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/messages.jl:78
     [28] #invokelatest#2
        @ ./essentials.jl:716 [inlined]
     [29] invokelatest
        @ ./essentials.jl:714 [inlined]
     [30] send_msg_(w::Distributed.Worker, header::Distributed.MsgHeader, msg::Distributed.CallMsg{:call_fetch}, now::Bool)
        @ Distributed /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/messages.jl:181
     [31] send_msg
        @ /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/messages.jl:122 [inlined]
     [32] remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Function, ::Vararg{Any}; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
        @ Distributed /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:464
     [33] remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Function, ::Vararg{Any})
        @ Distributed /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:461
     [34] #remotecall_fetch#158
        @ /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:496 [inlined]
     [35] remotecall_fetch
        @ /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:496 [inlined]
     [36] (::Distributed.var"#169#170"{typeof(+), var"#4#9"{Main.Quantum.var"#psetproposal#10"{Matrix{Float64}}, var"#target#8"{QRelaySampler, Vector{Int64}, Vector{Bool}}}, UnitRange{Int64}, Vector{UnitRange{Int64}}, Int64, Int64})()
        @ Distributed /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/macros.jl:270

Stacktrace:
 [1] wait
   @ ./task.jl:334 [inlined]
 [2] fetch
   @ ./task.jl:349 [inlined]
 [3] preduce(reducer::Function, f::Function, R::UnitRange{Int64})
   @ Distributed /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Distributed/src/macros.jl:274
 [4] macro expansion
   @ ./timing.jl:220 [inlined]
 [5] relay_basis(alpha::Float64, delta::Float64, name::String, n::Int64)
   @ Main ./In[3]:31
 [6] top-level scope
   @ ./In[4]:4
 [7] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [8] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1196
```

I understood that the error might have occurred in the for loop, if it is how can I use the `for` loop for parallel computing.

Comment: What are you expecting to be added in the `@distributed (+) for i= 2:samples` loop?

Comment: I'm expecting an array of arrays and these arrays are the ones that were selected after the MCMC condition was verified.

Comment: something like this: `[[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],.....]`